# Outsourcing of VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing different VBA functions that I want to use out of different Excel files. How can I "outsource" these VBA functions that I don't have to write them in every Excel file redundantly!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If they're brand new Excel files, I believe you can save them to the template and then new documents will have them by default.

Answer (score 4):

You could save your workbook as an add-in (.xlam) - an add-in loads with Excel, and runs at *application level*. You can reference an add-in in a macro-enabled workbook, and use the functions and objects it exposes:

[image: project explorer showing multiple .xlam projects and a VBAProject opened]

The flipside is that anyone using workbooks that reference an add-in, will require that add-in in order to work.